# duda de como plantear un listado listview en android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, listview, checkbox, guardar

me gustaría hacer con android studio lo siguiente,

que en un listview cada item tenga en vez de texto, 3 check box y un nombre
que al darle a un boton añadir, agrege un nuevo item al listview, que el nombre lo agrege de un campo de texto editable y los 3 Checkbox.

que al pulsar sobre un check se quede guardada esa opcion para cuando se cierre la app y al volverla a cargar (o refrescar el oncreate) se vea si cada una de las opciones de la lista tienen o no algo seleccionadao... y por ultimo un boton para borrar un item de ese listview...

el listview con un arraylist puedo hacerlo pero no se como guardar los item ni guardar los cambios pero lo que realmente necesito es como crear un item en ese arraylist que sea checkbox y no texto o numeros...

gracias.

Comment: Puedes agregar lo que has intentado y con el error que presentas? Si solo dices hagan este deber no es bien recibido.

Comment: nono no quiero el codigo, solo por ejemplo como podria poner en un arraylist un valor de checkbox y como guardar un listview para que se mantengan los cambios una vez se cierre la app, los métodos no el código es lo que busco, no tengo código escrito por que estoy en la parte de planteamiento

Answer (score 0):

```
si pongo el código como este solo me genera un listado del siguiente forma:

com.ebs.cuidados.animal@a234f3        V
com.ebs.cuidados.animal@faf4fV        
com.ebs.cuidados.animal@asdf4V        V

------------
private void initListViewData()  {

    animal donald = new animal("Donald", false,false,true);
    animal aaa = new animal("aaaaa");
    animal bbb = new animal("bbbbbbbbb", false,false,false);
    animal[] users = new animal[]{bbb,aaa, donald};

    // android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked:
    // ListItem is very simple (Only one CheckedTextView).
    ArrayAdapter<animal> arrayAdapter
            = new ArrayAdapter<animal>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, users);

  //pone el arrayadapter en el listview
    this.lv1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    for(int i=0;i< users.length; i++ )  {
        this.lv1.setItemChecked(i,users[i].isActive());
        this.lv1.setItemChecked(i,users[i].isActive2());
        this.lv1.setItemChecked(i,users[i].isActive3());
    }
}
```